electron-builder packaging prompts app.asar is used by other files. resource busy or locked, unlink app.asar
PS C:\app\electron-auto-tools> yarn build
yarn run v1.22.22
$ rimraf dist && rimraf release && cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192 vite build && yarn icon && electron-builder
[Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink 'C:\app\electron-auto-tools\release\5.8.0\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar'] {
  errno: -4082,
  code: 'EBUSY',
  syscall: 'unlink',
  path: 'C:\\app\\electron-auto-tools\\release\\5.8.0\\win-unpacked\\resources\\app.asar'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

After checking, I found that vscode was monitoring the release folder and could not be deleted. When I closed vscode, release could be deleted.
The relevant code repository is: https://github.com/pure-admin/electron-pure-admin

image link: https://s2.loli.net/2024/11/07/xaNABnYgwtW1shi.png
